# Kafka streams: Using the DSL api, within a transform, how can I send two messages to different topics/separate DSL downstream processors

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm using the DSL api and I have a use case where I need to check a condition and then if true, send an additional message to a separate topic from the happy path. My question is, how can I attach child processors to parents in the DSL api? Is it as simple as caching a stream variable and using it in two subsequent places, and naming those stream processors? Here's some brief code that explains what I'm trying to do. I am using the DSL api because I need the use of the foreignKeyJoin.

```
var myStream = stream.process(myProcessorSupplier); //3.3 returns a stream

stream.to("happyThingTopic"); Q: will the forward ever land here?

stream.map( myKvMapper, new Named("what-is-this")).to("myOtherTopic"); //will the forward land here?


public KeyValue<String, Object> process(Object key, Object value){
  if (value.hasFlag){
     processorContext.forward(key, new OtherThing(), "what-is-this?");
  }
  return new KeyValue(key, HappyThing(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created some sample code and unit test to prove the concept. It's possible to pick a specific logic path for a message to be forwarded downstream to. There is one gotcha however.

By returning the a value in the transform method, kafka streams still sends the original message to both child stream processors regardless if they are named or not.
You can prevent this from happening by:

- naming all child processors
- using processorContext.forward in the transformer to send ALL message downstream to various named processors
- and returning null in the transform

  ```
   package com.events.streams;

   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.To;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
   import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
   import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Profile("context-forward-poc")
   @Component
   @EnableKafka
   @ConditionalOnProperty(
       name = "kafka.enabled",
       havingValue = "true",
       matchIfMissing = true)
   public class KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig {

     public final static String childProcessorName = "forward-child";
     public final static String INPUT_TOPIC = "context.input.topic";
     public final static String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "context.output.topic";
     public final static String OUTPUT_FORWARD_TOPIC = "context.forward.output.topic";
     private final StreamsBuilder builder;

     public KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig(@Autowired
     @Qualifier(KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
     StreamsBuilder builder){
       this.builder = builder;
       initTopology();
     }

     private void initTopology(
         ) {
       KStream<String, String> stream = builder
           .stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
           .transform(PocTransformer::new);

       stream.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);
       stream
           .map((k,v)-> new KeyValue<>(k, v), Named.as(childProcessorName))
           .to(OUTPUT_FORWARD_TOPIC);
     }

     public static class PocTransformer implements Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>{

       private ProcessorContext context;

       @Override
       public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
         this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
         context.forward(key, "here-be-a-forwarded-message", To.child(childProcessorName));
         return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {

       }
     }
   }



   Unit Test

   package com.events.streams;

   import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

   import com.csx.events.MainApplication;
   import java.time.Instant;
   import java.util.Properties;
   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.TestInputTopic;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.TestOutputTopic;
   import org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
   import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration;
   import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

   @SpringBootTest(classes = {MainApplication.class, KafkaStreamsContextForwardTest.class, KStreamsBeans.class})
   @ActiveProfiles("context-forward-poc")
   @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
   public class KafkaStreamsContextForwardTest {


     private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KStreamsE2EForeignKeyJoinIT.class);

     @Autowired
     KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig kafkaStreamsConfig;

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier(KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
     StreamsBuilder builder;

     private TopologyTestDriver testDriver;
     private TestInputTopic<String, String> testInputTopic;
     private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopic;
     private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputContextForwardTopic;

     @BeforeAll
     public void setup() {

       Properties props = new Properties();
       props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "./target/kstreamsstate/KStreamChildProcessorTest");
       props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "KStreamChildProcessorTest");
       props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "KStreamChildProcessorTest:3212");
       props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
       props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());


       //the kafkaStreamsConfig class has already been loaded by the spring context so the topology exists here
       testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), props);


       testInputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic(
           KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig.INPUT_TOPIC,
           new StringSerializer(),
           new StringSerializer()
       );

       outputTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(
           KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig.OUTPUT_TOPIC,
           new StringDeserializer(),
           new StringDeserializer()
       );

       outputContextForwardTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(
           KafkaStreamsContextForwardPOCConfig.OUTPUT_FORWARD_TOPIC,
           new StringDeserializer(),
           new StringDeserializer()
       );
     }

     @Test
     void shouldReceiveForwardedMessage(){
       testInputTopic.pipeInput(
           "key1",
           "value1",
           Instant.now()
       );

       final KeyValue<String, String> outputTopicMessage = outputTopic.readKeyValue();
       final KeyValue<String, String> outputTopicMessageFromContextForward = outputContextForwardTopic.readKeyValue();
       assertEquals(outputTopicMessage.key, "key1");
       assertEquals(outputTopicMessage.value, "value1");
       assertEquals(outputTopicMessageFromContextForward.key, "key1");
       assertEquals(outputTopicMessageFromContextForward.value, "here-be-a-forwarded-message");

       //!!! By returning the happy path message in the transform method,
       // kafka streams still sends the original message to both child stream processors regardless if they are named or not.
       // You can prevent this from happening by:
       // * naming all child processors
       // * using processorContext.forward in the transformer to send ALL message downstream to various named processors
       // * and returning null in the transform
       // * Or you can do it on the backend and put a named filter processor on all your downstream child processors to weed out the ones you don't want
       // * I dislike the latter option because it's smelly.
       final KeyValue<String, String> outputTopicHappyPathMessageFromContextForward = outputContextForwardTopic.readKeyValue();
       assertEquals(outputTopicHappyPathMessageFromContextForward.key, "key1");
       assertEquals(outputTopicHappyPathMessageFromContextForward.value, "value1");
     }
   }
  ```